Why mock is returning the missing property?
I am not sure what I am doing wrong but here is the scenario for which I am trying to write the unit test using NUnit, Moq in C#
Model:
public class Model
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
}

Repo
public class Repo : IRepo
{
    public Model Execute(Datetime date)
    {
        // Calls DB Operation
        // Maps only two properties and didn't map Address1
        Id = Id,
        Name = Name
    }
}

Unit Test
public void UnitTestToMockDB()
{
    var mockRepo = new Mock<IRepo>();
    var expectedResult = new Model()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Username",
        Address1 = "Address line 1"
    };

    mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.Execute(It.IsAny<DateTime>())).Returns(expectedResult);
    var result = mockRepo.Object.Execute(DateTime.Now);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Id, result.Id);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Name, result.Name);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Address1, result.Address1); <-- Should fail.
}

To my surprise, result consists of the Address1 property, which it should not. What I am doing wrong? And why it is returning Address1?
In this case, both objects will always be same.
Asserts will always be true.
What I have to do to fix this?
PS: I don't have a service class, I just have a repo class.

Your mockRepo.Setup specified it to return expectedResult, which you defined to have Address line 1 as Address1. That Setup() means you're telling the unit test: If Execute() is called with any datetime, return expectedResult. It doesn't have anything to do with your Repo class.

What should I defined in this case? I am not familiar with mocking.

Remove Address1 = "Address line 1" in your unit test.

What should I Assert with then?

Depends on what would you want to unit test on. An unit test should have an idea of what it should test, for example, Execute() should request data from db with the parameter? Execute() shouldn't assign Address1? etc. Read up on introduction about unit tests, think about what you need to test first.

Why do I need to request data from db? I am trying to Mock a db call.

Because in actual code the data should be queried from a database, so one possible unit test is to test This function should interact with DbContext, to make sure that the function didn't just respond with hard-coded data. Check out online tutorials to understand more basics about unit tests.

//Why do I need to request data from db? I am trying to Mock a db call.// Basically we are testing the production code. that means the actual code which is going to run in production after release. In unit testing you should provide a test double (or mock) of db  to actual code of Repo.  Remember we are testing the actual code of Repo with mock of db. But you are testing the mock of Repo itself which is meaningless

We mock a class/method to be faked in behavior like input/output. Keep in mind when you mock a method, that method won't call, actually what mocking libraries do is override the method implementation and put a fake one by just returning the result you specified, or in case of mocking interface they will add their own implementation class and faking all methods.
Based on the code, we tell the mock lib if the Execute gets called with any params then please return expectedResult without running the actual Execute method body.
So, the test is working as expected.
Better to write an integration test for the repo, IMO. because this unit test is useless.
If you really want to write a unit test, I would suggest to mock the DB operation instead and let Execute do its job.
Given the repo, the class has a constructor param for DB operations (just assuming) then the test will be like this:
public void UnitTestToMockDB()
    {
        var mockDb = new Mock<IDbOperations>();
        var expectedDbResult = new DbModel()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Username",
            Address1 = "Address line 1"
        };
        mockDb.Setup(db=> db.GetUserByDate(It.IsAny<DateTime>())).Returns(expectedDbResult);
        
        var actualRepo = new Repo(mockDb);
        
        var result = actualRepo.Execute(DateTime.Now);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Id, result.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult.Name, result.Name);
        Assert.Null(result.Address1);
    }


Here Code Under Test is Repo class. We can call it Subject Under Test (SUT) or Component Under Test (CUT) as well.  Each unit test will check/test a Unit of Work. Generally, Unit of Work is a method and Execute method is unit of work in this case.
In unit testing, we are checking whether the Unit of Work is behaving as expected for a given Scenario. Remember we are checking the actual code which is going to run in production environment after release. The Unit test will invoke the Unit of Work during development, deployment, merging and more places in SDLC.  We will be writing separate tests for each Scenario. Each test will check for respective behavior by invoking the "Unit of Work". We can think "Scenario" as input to Unit of Work and "Behavior" as output of Unit of Work.
Any SUT may have dependencies to be exist and to do its job. If SUT is a class/object, it's dependencies are the properties or fields which set through constructors, properties or methods. In provided code I can't see the dependencies for the SUT i.e. Repo class. As User @sa-es-ir assumes (IDbOperations), there must be a dependency to interact with database.
Scenario comprises of State of Dependencies, behavior of Dependencies and State of SUT. In a unit test, we set up a scenario so that unit test will check for corresponding behavior mechanistically or repeatedly. To have a desired behavior of Dependency, we have to pass in the test-double of the dependency instead of actual dependency to the SUT. That's where we would need a mocking tool or framework like Moq. Mock is one of the types of Test-Double.
//What I am doing wrong? //
Answer: But here you have created test-double for the SUT itself. And you invoked the test-double instead of invoking the actual "Unit of Work".
//And why it is returning Address1?//
Answer: Because It is a test-double. Colloquially people call it as "mock" instead of "test double". You setup the test double mockRepo to return the expectedResult with "Address line 1" as value for the property Address1 for the method Execute as below.
mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.Execute(It.IsAny<DateTime>())).Returns(expectedResult);

And you invoked the method of mockRepo which you have setup as above , so it behaved or returned the expectedResult as you arranged.
var result = mockRepo.Object.Execute(DateTime.Now);

The answer shows correctly by setting up scenario aka arranging dependency and invoking the actual "Unit of Work" of SUT. Unit test needs actual/real/production code of SUT since it is testing that part of production code after all.
